# How is it true that the maximum of $a^Tx$ inside of a Euclidean ball with radius $r$ equal to $r\|a\|_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am seeing in my textbook that the following is true:

*The maximum value for $a^Tx$ inside of a Euclidean ball with radius $r$ equal to $r\lVert a \rVert_2$.    Put another way*:

$$ \sup\{a^Tx \mid \lVert x\rVert_2\le r\}=r\lVert a\rVert_2$$

*where:*

$x$ *is a vector variable*,

$a$ *is a constant vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$*

$r$ *is the radius of the Euclidean ball $\in \mathbb{R}$*

I do not understand how the above equation makes sense.

I have a feeling it has something to do with the fact that these two planes are orthogonal $P_1=\{x \mid a^Tx=b\}$ and $P_2=\{x \mid ka=x\}$ .  Because I know that we can find an equation for the vector that passes through the center of the Euclidean circle, and is orthogonal to the supporting hyperplane.  And, the distance from the center of the Euclidean ball, to the supporting hyperplane, is going to be along that plane $P_2$.    But I cannot formalize this logic to show how the aforementioned statement in my textbook is true.

Can someones help me with this?  thanks

Comment: Let $x = \frac{r}{\|a\|} a$; what's $a^T x$?

Comment: but why is $x=(r/||a||) a$?

Comment: @Candic3 You can pick any $x$ in the ball of radius $r$. It turns out that picking one in the same direction as $a$ makes the inner product big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:** By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have for $\|x\|_2 \leq r$
$$ \langle a, x\rangle_2 =|a^\top x | \leq \|a\|_2 \|x\| \leq r\|a\|_2. $$
Now consider $\bar x := \frac{r}{\|a\|_2} a$ and calculate $a^\top \bar x$ and  $\|\bar x \|_2$.